# Event Emitter gets emmited multiple times , Nest JS

Tags: nestjs, eventemitter

I am new to Event Emitters and tried implementing them in my Nest JS project, the problem is that the same event gets triggered multiple times (6 times to be exact) , any reason as to why and how to resolve this ?

This is the code snippet in the **service.ts** file to emit the event.
`this.eventEmitter.emit('company.created', companyCreatedHistory);`

This is my Event , in the ***listener.ts*** file

```
@Injectable()
export class EntityCreatedListener {
  constructor(private readonly historyService: HistoriesService) {}

  @OnEvent('company.created')
  handleCompanyCreatedEvent(eventObject: typeof eventEmitterObject) {
    console.log('Hi')
    this.createAuditLog(eventObject, 'company.created');
  }
```

Referred from : https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/30-event-emitter
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/event-emitter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So looking at your code I am guessing the problem is because you have different instances of the `EntityCreatedListener` flying around in your application. You probably have instantiated it 6 times that's why the event is firing 6 times.

All these instances of the `EntityCreatedListener` will be listening for the `company.created` event and will fire once this method call `this.eventEmitter.emit('company.created', companyCreatedHistory);` triggers the event.

**THE FIX WOULD BE:** Check the modules in your application and make sure the `EntityCreatedListener` is not imported in multiple places in the provider imports on this section of the module code `@Module({imports: [],controllers: [],providers: []})`. Keep only one instance of the `EntityCreatedListener` (thus it should be imported in only one module and shared to other modules by exporting it if you want to use in multiple places)